# What is the right formula to make a button title tested?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I know that it sounds weird but my project is making **TIC TAC TOE** in iPhone and I want to test if the button text equals to **X** or not

I tried to type this formula but it failed and I understood that the computer didn't read the "X" because I made it NULL and it was ran,

```
if ((([button1.titleLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@" " ]   && [button2.titleLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@" " ]
&& [button3.titleLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@" " ]  ))
```

Answer (score 2):

`randomButton`'s titleLabel is a string and so you can use `isEqualToString:`

```
if ([randomButton.titleLabel isEqualToString:@""]){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A computer can't but `iPhone` can! :)

To compare title text of `UIButton` you should use `isEqualToString:`

```
if([yourButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"X"])
{
    //Do something ...
}
```

P.S. Computer or in any cheap programming, it only understand [`binary-language`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code) (sometimes called `machine-language`) made of `0 & 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Check like this:

```
if(button1.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"X"])
{ //YES
  //do something
}
else
{ //NO
  //do something
}
```